# Unable to find any .xccoverage file while running xcov with fastlane

Tags: ios, xcode, code-coverage, fastlane

This is what fastlane prints in console:

```
[10:25:55]: Unable to find any .xccoverage file.
[10:25:55]: Make sure you have enabled 'Gather code coverage' setting on your scheme settings.
[10:25:55]: Alternatively you can provide the full path to your .xccoverage file.
```

**How can I force it to provide the full path to my `.xccoverage` file?**

- I am pretty sure Gather coverage is enabled;)
- Using Xcode 10 and iOS 12, Swift 4.2

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this problem during migration to Swift 4.2 and XCode 10.

Did you update your xcov to version 1.5?
It resolved the problem for me.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you! "bundle update xcov". I keep thinking that updating fastlane also updates the rest.

Comment: FWIW, I'm seeing the same problem with Xcode 10 and xcov 1.5.